# nodejs - "open" package don`t work in heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, docx

I trying to open a docx document in the browser,

I have this dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "log-timestamp": "^0.3.0",
    "open": "^8.2.1"
  },
```

In my localhost node server work, but no in heroku, this is a log:

[image]

"File closed" is a console log that execute when the docx is closes, it means that it closes immediately, without opening the docx.

Anybody know how can i open the file with node?

Comment: EDIT: open package doesn`t work on heroku, the .docx file closed automatically. This only work on a pc desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open package doesn`t work on heroku, the .docx file closed automatically. This only work on a pc desktop.